# Why this SELECT statment expect INTO clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am confusing a little bit

```
FUNCTION IF_FORTNOX_EXIST(p_clientId IN INT)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
    SELECT *    
    FROM fortnox_cron_job  WHERE ContentID = p_clientId AND ContentType = 'Client';
    RETURN rc;
END IF_FORTNOX_EXIST;
```

Once I create function and compile it I get error and I dont know why ?
And how to form these SELECT statment to work properly ?

```
Error(39,5): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use like this

```
FUNCTION IF_FORTNOX_EXIST(p_clientId IN INT)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
AS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

OPEN rc FOR 
  SELECT *    
  FROM fortnox_cron_job  
  WHERE ContentID = p_clientId 
  AND ContentType = 'Client';

  RETURN rc;
END IF_FORTNOX_EXIST;
```

Comment: It is returning a cursor so better call this function in oracle form to check, not  in SQL developer.

Comment: Thank you, I just see that I miss `OPEN rc FOR` :)